# How to Increase (AKKA-HTTP Client) singleRequest response chuck size

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am reading an HTTP Response stream from a URL.
The response runForeach returns a stream of small chunks.
I want to increase the chunk size.

I have an application.conf file where I experimented with the following (increasing default values), but nothing changed. Wasn't sure which config param is the one I need. I must be doing something wrong.

application.conf:

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing.max-chunk-size=50m
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing.max-chunk-ext-length=50m
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing.max-content-length=50m
```

my code:

```
var config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()

implicit val system = ActorSystem("test", config)
import system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = source))

responseFuture.flatMap { response =>
   val responseData = response.entity.dataBytes
   responseData.runForeach(chunk => {
     println(s"CHUNK:${chunk}")
   })
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max-chunk-size` is a protection against filling memory, it will fail the request if the server would respond with larger chunks, it does not dictate the size of the chunks in any other way.

The chunk size is dictated by things such as OS network buffers, network packet size, the server responding with http chunks, etc. you cannot really say "I want 50m chunks".

What you can do is to concatenate the incoming `ByteString`s, into 50mb chunks, `concat` is a zero copy operation so the overhead should be fairly low.

There is an example in the Akka Streams docs of how to create a custom graph stage that does "rechunking" that might be useful here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#chunking-up-a-stream-of-bytestrings-into-limited-size-bytestrings

Comment: Thank you. Could be useful to add to the docs. Also got to look at conflate.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation describes a setup of these properties - [link to documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.10/scala/http/configuration.html) :

> IMPORTANT: Please note that this sections settings can be overriden by
>   the corresponding settings in: `akka.http.server.parsing`,
>   `akka.http.client.parsing` or
>   `akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing`.

Maybe you should try config `akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.parsing` and `akka.http.server.parsing`.

Comment: I was already using the "host-connection-pool.client". I added the server per your suggestion. Alas it doesn't seem to have an affect still. Thank you for the suggestion.